# select first element of the same class

Tags: html, css, less

How to access first of many grouped element of the same class?
Lets say i have something that looks like this:

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
</div>

<div class="group">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
</div>

<div class="group">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to change style for ONLY the first element of each group. How can this be achieved? I tried

```
.group{
    .element:first{
        ####styles here
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work unfortunately(should it?).

Comment: Why would you expect `:first` to work when it's not documented anywhere?

Comment: coworker told me to use it and i didnt bother checking it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:first-child`.

```css
.group .element:first-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
    <div class="element">Test</div>
    <div class="element">Test</div>
    <div class="element">Test</div>
    <div class="element">Test</div>
</div>

<div class="group">
    <div class="element">Test</div>
    <div class="element">Test</div>
    <div class="element">Test</div>
    <div class="element">Test</div>
</div>

<div class="group">
    <div class="element">Test</div>
    <div class="element">Test</div>
    <div class="element">Test</div>
    <div class="element">Test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using

```
.group .element:first-child{
    color: red;
}
```

Note: There is no such selector as `:first` in css which was mentioned in your question.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7gn8zb4g/)**

Answer (score 0):

In case the `.element` will be the first element of its parent. You may use:

```
.element:first-child {
  /* styles here */
}
```

This won't work in case there is any tag before `<div class="element">...</div>`in your HTML.

See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child).

Answer (score 0):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/n2f8ko6y/

documentation of [**first-child**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)

```
.group {
    .element:first-child {
        color: red;
    }
}
```