# How to select the first element on a page using a particular class when each subsequent element using the same class is also a first child?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I'm making a Fibonacci spiral. Code below. I need to create a second layer of the spiral (a spiral is made with a series of nested divs) and am creating multiple layers using the for loop.
I need to change the height of the first div element in the file with class .item-one, no subsequent divs with class .item-one.

How do I select just the first one, bearing in mind there will be a further 4 div elements with class .item-one which are also all the first child of their parents, using just CSS and vanilla JS?
(I need to change the height of just the first one and need all the rest of the .item-one divs to be a different height.)

I've tried :first-child and :first-of-type but all .item-one elements are the first children of their respective parents, so both :first-child and :first-of-type select all of the .item-one elements, not just the first on the page.
This post [select first element of the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27166936/select-first-element-of-the-same-class) is close, except the solution selects all first child elements, whereas I only want to select the first div in the file with that class.

### Code:

HTML

```
<div class="item-one">
  <div class="item-two">
    <div class="item-three">
      <div class="item-four"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

  var $items = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
  var $item = $items[0];
  var $cloned_item = $item.cloneNode(true);
  var $final_item = $items[$items.length - 1];

  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    $final_item.appendChild($cloned_item);
    $final_item = $items[$items.length - 1];
    $cloned_item = $item.cloneNode(true);
  }

});
```

The end result looks something like this.

```
<div class="item-one">
  <div class="item-two">
    <div class="item-three">
      <div class="item-four">
        <div class="item-one">
          <div class="item-two">
            <div class="item-three">
              <div class="item-four">
                <div class="item-one">
                  <div class="item-two">
                    <div class="item-three">
                      <div class="item-four">...and so on...</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use the parent of the first `<div class="item-one">` in your CSS rule, or else you won't be able to solve that w/o script

Comment: I would add an additional class to each div, which tells you which group it is a member of -- it adds a logic to your code that is missing.

`<div class="item-one one">
  <div class="item-two one">
    <div class="item-three one">
      <div class="item-four one">
        <div class="item-one two">
          <div class="item-two two">
            <div class="item-three two">
              <div class="item-four two">
                <div class="item-one three">
                  <div class="item-two three">...and so on...</div>`

Comment: @LGSon thanks! I was trying to over-complicate it with :first-child etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to use the parent to be able to single out the first child element. I used body in this case, but if you have a different parent then you'd use that.

```css
body > .item-one {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-one">
  <div class="item-two">
    <div class="item-three">
      <div class="item-four">
        <div class="item-one">
          <div class="item-two">
            <div class="item-three">
              <div class="item-four">
                <div class="item-one">
                  <div class="item-two">
                    <div class="item-three">
                      <div class="item-four">...and so on...</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or better would be to just give that outer div another class and use that if that's an option.

Answer (score 0):

Does that what you are looking for?

```css
div {border: 1px solid blue;}
.item-one {border: 1px solid yellow;}
body > .item-one {border: 2px solid red;}
```

```html
<div class="item-one">
  <div class="item-two">
    <div class="item-three">
      <div class="item-four">
        <div class="item-one">
          <div class="item-two">
            <div class="item-three">
              <div class="item-four">
                <div class="item-one">
                  <div class="item-two">
                    <div class="item-three">
                      <div class="item-four">...and so on...</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Edit after @LGSon open eyes comments.

Comment: You need to read up on `first-of-type`, as it works for siblings, not descendants

Comment: So the fact that this is working depends on my FF and every other browser act differently? I'll sure read it right now.

Comment: well, according to mdn: Note: As originally defined, the selected element had to have a parent. Beginning with Selectors Level 4, this is no longer required. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type

Comment: I never said it needs a parent, I said `first-of-type` targets siblings, and is OP's case there is only one element in each level, having a child, not sibling.

Comment: In your sample `first-of-type` is meaningless given their is only one element on each level, and can mislead users believe it is needed...it still works though.

Comment: Thanks...and no need to apologize, you weren't unkind :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the > selector to apply the styling to the immediate first child of its parent with the `.item-one` class. If you don't have a parent for all of those elements, then using the body should do.

```css
body>.item-one {
    /* Styling here */
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 5px black solid;
}
```

Comment: @LGSon. You need to read up on `first-of-type`, as nested elements can also be targeted. Note that the universal selector (*) is implied when no simple selector is written. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type.
Btw: This actually works. I've tried it myself before posting it.

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't work, I said `first-of-type` target siblings, not descendants.

Comment: Nested elements can also be targeted

Comment: In your sample `first-of-type` is meaningless, and can mislead users believe it is needed, hence my downvote.